# ruby on rails 4 - multiple forms for same model on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application there is a User-model and a Task-model. The user can create tasks and manage them. But now I want the users to be able to fill in the forms of multiple task on one page.

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

 def new
    @task = current_user.tasks.build
 end

  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

    if @task.save
      redirect_to @task, notice: "Task erstellt"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def edit
end

def update
  if @task.update(task_params)
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @task.destroy
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Task gelöscht"
end

def show
end

def index
  @tasks = Task.all.order("created_at DESC")
end

private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :urgency, :importance, :time)
end

def find_task
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

new.html.haml

```
- 6.times do
= form_for @task do |t|
    = t.text_field :name
    %br
    = t.text_area :description  
    %br
    = t.text_field :urgency
    %br
    = t.text_field :importance
    %br
    = t.text_field :time
    %br
= t.submit "Bestätigen"
```

But this doesn't work obviosly. I get the following error:

> ArgumentError in Tasks#new
>   Showing C:/Sites/taskr4/app/views/tasks/new.html.haml where line #13 raised:
>
> wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
>    Rails.root: C:/Sites/taskr4
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/tasks/new.html.haml:13:in `block in >_app_views_tasks_new_html_haml__991073273_86859300'
>   app/views/tasks/new.html.haml:1:in`times'
>   app/views/tasks/new.html.haml:1:in >`_app_views_tasks_new_html_haml__991073273_86859300'

Comment: Please post detailed error log, "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)" for what ?

Answer (score 2):

What's your exception backtrace? from your post, I think there should have any error.

By the way, if you want create or edit multiple tasks, please take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually.

```
<% form_tag create_multiple_tasks_path, :method => :put do %>
  <% 6.times do %>
    <% fields_for "tasks[]", Task.new do |f| %>
      <h2><%=h task.name %></h2>
      <%= render "fields", :f => f %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>


def create_multiple
  @tasks = params[:tasks].map do |task_params|
     Project.new(task_params).save
     # TODO: add validate and error messages.
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the error **undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: did you have any input in the form when you submit?

Comment: Also the line `<% for task in @tasks %>` doesnt work. I changed it to `<% 6.times do%>` Maybe thats a problem?

Comment: did you initial @tasks in the controller#new >

Comment: alright, so I have to define a `new_multiple` action in the controller but what to put inside? `@tasks = current_user.tasks.build`?

Comment: @tasks = [Task.new] * 10

Comment: <% 6.times do %>
    <% fields_for "tasks[]", Task.new do |f| %>
      <h2><%=h task.name %></h2>
      <%= render "fields", :f => f %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

Comment: Still getting the same error. I guess there is something wrong with the params.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way in Rails to instanciate several times the same standalone model without reworking your controller and your view. However, if your User model `has_many :tasks` then you can take advantage of nested forms/attributes which will let you create forms where you can add several tasks to a user.

There are several gems which make this trivial. For example you might want to have a look at what you can do with the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem.

However if you really want to have a standalone form to instanciate several tasks, eg. for different users, then I'm afraid you'll have extra work, which is not that easy to figure out. Basically you need to define `new_multiple` and `create_multiple` actions in your controller, and figure out how to write your HTML view so when you POST it, the parameters are interpreted as an array of tasks. ie you want `params[:tasks]` to return an array in your controller, so you can do something like `params[:tasks].each {|task_params| Task.create(task_params) }`

Comment: Could you explain your last idea more in detail please, I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: Which one ? The nested association `has_many :tasks` ? or the more complex one ?

Comment: I might get something wrong, but I think nested association wouldnt work.

Comment: Well it seems @user2130345 has already coded what I was thinking about.

Comment: I got some errors when I try to use the solution of @user2130345, but thank you anyway.